# Can we get prefetch_related result in same queryset while using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I don't want to query again from Model_B, can I get that result from same queryset in Django model?

```
queryset = Model_A.objects.prefetch_related('Model_B')
```

Comment: That is the general idea of prefetch/select_related (if its a 1:1 use select related). Then when you use Model_A.Model_B.some_attr you wont be doing a second query. To note when you prefetch related you do it for a 1:many and will always do at least 2 queries